# Spyder 4.0.1 How can we get console output without using a print statement?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

For example in Spyder 3.3.6, we can have a 1+1 cell that outputs 2 in the console without using print(1+1). Is it possible to have the same functionalities in Spyder 4.0.1?

Edit: Running a 1+1 cell in Spyder 4.0.1 would not have an output. I want to know if there's a setting I can change for it to output 2.

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/internalconsole.html).

Comment: Please see above the question this one is a duplicate of.